# Make a multiline checkbox in Material (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a checkbox I want to have a label with a multiline. How can you break the label of this?

```
 <mat-checkbox>a somewhat longer label!</mat-checkbox>
```

I tried with css

```
mat-checkbox span { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

but that looks weird

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is an existing issue about this [on github](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8416), but here is a workaround.

**Update: From Angular 15 and on:**

To style the checkbox for the current component, just add the following to the component.css file:

```
:host::ng-deep.mat-mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox {
  margin-top: -0.5em !important;
}
:host::ng-deep.mat-mdc-checkbox .mdc-form-field {
  align-items: start !important;
}
```

If you want to apply it to all checkboxes of the entire app. Add the following to styles.css:

```
.mat-mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox {
  margin-top: -0.5em !important;
}
.mat-mdc-checkbox .mdc-form-field {
  align-items: start !important;
}
```

**Prior to Angular version 15:**

To style the checkbox for the current component, just add the following to the component.css file:

```
:host::ng-deep.mat-checkbox-layout{
white-space: normal !important;
}

:host::ng-deep.mat-checkbox-inner-container{
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

If you want to apply it to all checkboxes of the entire app. Add the following to styles.css:

```
.mat-checkbox-layout{
white-space: normal !important;

}
.mat-checkbox-inner-container{
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! In my case (Angular 12), it was actually better without setting margin-top.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the example, bootstrap text-wrap class used

```
<mat-checkbox>
   <div class="text-wrap">
    a somewhat longer label!
   </div>
 </mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any case where overflowing is preferable to going multiline. The problem can be fixed for all `mat-checkbox` by placing this in the styles.scss file of the projet (which is the file where `@include mat-core();` is called):

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
.mat-checkbox-layout {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
// place the fix before mat-core() mixin
@include mat-core();
```

Comment: This works great. Can you make it top aligned too? So that the checkbox and the first line align vertically?

Answer (score 0):

In case of you're using Tailwind, just add `.whitespace-pre-wrap`:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="termsAccepted" color="primary">
    <div class="whitespace-pre-wrap">{{ 'I accept' | translate }}</div>
</mat-checkbox>
```